# Nested fields not being created on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am trying to get a Project form to build the first (starting) time of several (up to 12) volunteer time blocks.

`project.rb`

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, ...
  has_many :vol_times, :dependent => destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vol_times, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:start_time].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
  ...
end
```

`vol_time.rb`

```
class Vol_time < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :start_time, ...
  belongs_to :project
end
```

`ProjectsController`

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: :create
  ...
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    @user = current_user
    @project.vol_times.build
  end
  ...
end
```

`Vol_Times Controller`

```
class Vol_TimesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @reward = Reward.new
  end
  ...
end
```

My view looks like this...

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>

<div class="form_field_block">
      <p class="form_label">&nbsp;&nbsp;Project Title</p>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :size => 40, :placeholder => " Project Title...", :class => "frm" %>
</div>
<div class="form_field_block">
  <p class="form_label">&nbsp;&nbsp;Project Sub-title</p>
    <%= f.text_field :sub_title, :size => 40, :placeholder => "  Project Sub-title...", :class => "frm" %>
</div>
<p class="clearing"></p>
<div class="form_field_block">
  <% f.fields_for :vol_times do |builder| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'start_time', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>
</div>    
<p class="clearing"></p>
<%= button_tag "btn_start_project.png", :class => "btn_save" %>
<% end %>
```

And the `_partial` looks like this...

```
<%= f.label :start_time, "Starting Time" %>
<%= f.text_field :start_time %>
```

When I view the page, I see the containing `<div>`, but not the contents of the ERB, which should be parsed from the `_partial`.

Any ideas why this isn't working?  I got the general context from Ryan Bates' RailsCast #196 - [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a `=` on the `fields_for`. It should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :vol_times do |builder| %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the generation issue, but now I'm getting 

`NameError in Projects#new undefined local variable or method 'f' for #<#<Class`

called on the `_partial` on line #1:

`1: <%= f.label :vol_times, "Starting Time" %>`

`<%= f.text_field :vol_times, :size => 20, :placeholder => "  Starting Time...", :class => "frm"%>`

Comment: Ok, for those who may follow afterwards, the error in the comments above is due to the inclusion of `:partial =>` in the render.  It should read:    

`<%= render 'start_time', :f => builder %>`

Comment: the original syntax for rendering a partial is `<%= render :partial => 'start_time', :locals => { :f => builder } %>`.  What you did is a shortcut and is preferred because it's cleaner.  If you need to pass other options like `collection` and `as`, you still need to use the original syntax.